# Convergence in distribution for nonnegative R.V.s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

> **Problem.** Let $Z, Z_1, Z_2, \cdots, Z_n$ be non-negative R.V.s with integer values. Prove that $Z_n \to Z$ in distribution, i.f.f $Pr(Z_n=t) \to Pr(Z=t)$ for all non-negative $t \in N$.

I have read about the Portmanteau theorem which states that if $ E_n f \to Ef$, then $P_n \to P$, P being the probability measure. Does this theorem apply in this case? (I was thinking convergence in distribution implies convergence in expectation.) thanks in advance.

Comment: Convergence in distribution does not imply convergence in expectation in general.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can utilize the Portnamteau theorem. Let me prove that

- $\mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \to \mathsf{P}[Z = t]$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}_0$ implies $Z_n \stackrel{d}{\to} Z$.

To this end, we prove the following simple lemma:

> **Lemma.** If $p_n, q_n \geq 0$ and $\sum_n p_n = \sum_n q_n < \infty$, then $$ \sum_n \left| p_n - q_n \right| = 2\sum_n (p_n - q_n)_+, $$
>   where $x_+ = \max\{x, 0\}$.

Indeed, by using the identity$|x| = 2x_+ - x$, we have

$$ \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left| p_n - q_n \right|
= \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} 2\left( p_n - q_n \right)_+ - \underbrace{\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left( p_n - q_n \right)}_{=0}. $$

Now we apply this lemma to our problem. Let $f$ be an arbitrary bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then with $\|f\|_{\sup} := \sup\{ |f(x)| : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\left| \mathsf{E}[f(Z)] - \mathsf{E}[f(Z_n)] \right|
&= \left| \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} f(t) \left( \mathsf{P}[Z = t] - \mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \right) \right| \\
&\leq \| f\|_{\sup} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left| \mathsf{P}[Z = t] - \mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \right| \\
&= 2 \| f\|_{\sup} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left( \mathsf{P}[Z = t] - \mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \right)_+ .
\end{align*}

Now the summand, as function of $t \in \mathbb{N}_0$, is dominated by the integrable function $t \mapsto \mathsf{P}[Z = t]$ (with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}_0$, of course) and hence by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \left( \mathsf{P}[Z = t] - \mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \right)_+
= \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \mathsf{P}[Z = t] - \mathsf{P}[Z_n = t] \right)_+
= 0 $$

by the assumption. Therefore $\mathsf{E}[f(Z_n)] \to \mathsf{E}[f(Z)]$ as required, and since this is true for any bounded continuous $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, the conclusion follows from the Portmanteau theorem.

Comment: i am a little confused by the frist inequality is ||f|| sup the maxmimum of f(Zn) and f(Z)?

Comment: or is it the upper bound of all f(Zn) functin o assuming f(zn) i sbounded by a integrable function g?

Comment: @jamesblack, It even does not involve neither of $Z$ or $Z_n$; it is simply the supremum of the values $|f(x)|$ over all real $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I added this explanation to my answer.

Comment: sorry i did not read that clearly, so why is f(x) bounded?

Comment: @jamesblack, Because we assumed so. Portmanteau theorem tells that it suffices to test the convergence $\mathsf{E}f(Z_n) \to \mathsf{E}f(Z)$ for bounded continuous functions $f$.

Comment: so portmans theorem works in both directions? and orry ididnt learn bout portman thm yet all i did was LLN and central limit thm, is it possible to use these two to prove this at all?

Comment: I am not sure which version of convergence in distribution is adopted as definition in your context (because there are several, equivalent way of defining this), but if it is defined in terms of vague convergence (i.e. convergence of c.d.f at each continuity point), then you can adapt the above argument to produce a direct proof of vague convergence $F_{Z_n} \to F_Z$. And the other direction should be much easier...

Comment: thanks so much, one last thing i understand [Z=t]−[Zn=t] is bounded by [Z=t] since [Zn=t]>0; but what is the integrable function t? and why does that make the lim converge to 0?

Comment: To answer that question, it seems crucial that you provide your background on this material. Assuming that you are learning probability in measure-theoretic formulation, note that $p(t) = (\mathsf{P}[Z=t]-\mathsf{P}[Z_n=t])_+$ is a function on $\mathbb{N}_0$ which is dominated by $f_n(t) = \mathsf{P}[Z=t]$ and $g$ is in $L^1(\#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}_0$. (I.e. $\int g(t)\,\#(dt)=\sum_{t\geq0}g(t)<\infty$.) So by the dominated convergence theorem, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{t\geq0}f_n(t)=\sum_{t\geq0}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t)=\sum_{t\geq0}0=0.$$

Comment: i only leanred bout dominated convergence theorem in terms of Xn converging to X then E(Xn) converges to E(X); however, i did some resaerch, and can we say that sum is dominated by the number 1? since sum of prob should be 1 and since P(Zn=t) converges to P(Z=t), the difference btween the two is 0?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you are asking. Here what is crucial that $p(t):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}[Z_n=t]$ again defines a probability measure, which does not merely follow from the existence of $p(t)$'s in general. Indeed, in this kind of business one needs a certain 'mass-conservation condition', which ensures that no mass escapes toward infinity. $\sum_{t\geq0} p(t) = 1$ is one such condition, but simply telling that $\sum_{t\geq0}\mathsf{P}[Z_n=t]=1$ for all $n$ is not enough.

Comment: sorry but i guess my question is just why the sum is dominated by the integrable function t↦[Z=t]? is f=t the function? or is f=P(z=t) the function? (which you typed in the comments, and shouldn't it be lim sum of p(t) not fn(t)?) sorry for being confusing but i am pretty confused by this

Comment: I see, I was not careful when explaining that part. I fixed the answer. Hope this is clearer now. Also, forgive me for leaving now and going to bed.